# Getting past warning MSB8029 using Windows Bridge for IOS

Tags: windows

Using Windows Bridge for IOS in a parallels Mac environment I'm getting "Warning MSB8029    The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build." A similar question was answered here earlier with a solution that required -- fixing the environment variables so the output directory pointed to the user's temp directory. I find that the environment variables were already set as recommended on this system and of course get the same warning. But I don't understand how the solution to such a message could involve pointing the output to a temp directory. Am I nuts? I found this recommended cure when trying to solve "could not acquire lock file for module 'QuartzCore' - the recommended solution for this, at GitHub, is to change the output directory to a local temp directory. Going in circles here.

Comment: [tag:winobjc] Got rid of the Quartz reference and now get "could not acquire lock file for module 'UIKit' for the first file that includes <UIKit\UIKit.h> - I have set the project's sdk path to the winobjc folder on the win partition. Set the output directory to user Temp directory as recommended (but of course still get the warning that the temp directory is not the way to go).

Comment: [tag winobjc] Let me do a partial answer on my own; other answers appreciated. What seems to work is ignoring the advice given at GitHub; rather than setting the output to the user's temp directory, I set the output to a directory I created at root level on the C: drive. This works - though I still get the MSB8029 warning the output is now directed to that location, and I no longer get the lock file errors. What I'm getting now are the expected errors for translation to the other environment, and I think I can deal with those.